# Admin role automatically unchecked when role is edited Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, user-roles, admin-user, role

I have a problem on my Magento webiste and I can't figure why is this happened.

I have 2 admin roles: **administrator** and **shopmanager**. Administrator role has all the permissions and shopmanager has custom permissions. There are two users registered, one is **administrator_user** and the other is **shopmanager_user**.

When I edit the shopmanager role (give more permissions or delete some permissions) the role of the shopmanager_user is automatically unchecked, and there is no role checked for this user, therefore shopmanager_user can't login until the administrator will check the user role again.

Did anyone has this problem because I don't know where to look? Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after searching and searching on Google and debugging my code, I found where is the problem but I don't know exactly why is the problem. When permission role is edited in `RoleController` in `saveRoleAction()` method all the users all deleted from the role and then are again added, the code is:

```
foreach($oldRoleUsers as $oUid) {
    $this->_deleteUserFromRole($oUid, $role->getId());
}

foreach ($roleUsers as $nRuid) {
    $this->_addUserToRole($nRuid, $role->getId());
}
```

So the user is deleted but in the `_addUserToRole()` method

```
protected function _addUserToRole(){
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($userId);
    $user->setRoleId($roleId)->setUserId($userId);

    if( $user->roleUserExists() === true ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        $user->add();
        return true;
    }
}
```

the `roleUserExists()` returns true, so the user isn't added again. I couldn't find why this method returns true, because the role is deleted from `admin_role` table, so I changed `_addUserToRole()` method code like this:

```
protected function _addUserToRole(){
    $user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($userId);
    $user->setRoleId($roleId)->setUserId($userId);

    $user->add();
    return true;
}
```

and now everything work fine and user role doesn't uncheck anymore. I know this is not the best way to do it but it works fine for me.